# Add placeholder text to input field in a Smart Capture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

I am trying to make a placeholder text in an input field, but having a hard time making this work. 
I tried within the js of the capture for
`document.getElementsByName("toEmail")[0].placeholder = "Email*";` but it doesn't get set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the following before the closing `</form>` tag when editing the Smart Capture block's HTML:

```
<script>
var formInputToEmail = document.getElementsByName('toEmail');
var placeholderToEmail = document.createAttribute('placeholder');
placeholderToEmail.value = 'Email*';
formInputToEmail[0].setAttributeNode(placeholderToEmail);
</script>
```

The above code snippet assumes the following:

- The `name` attribute value of your input field is exactly "toEmail" (JavaScript is case-sensitive)
- "toEmail" is unique (i.e., no other input fields have this attribute value for `name`)